# Math Stack Exchange Top User Swag

Tags: discussion

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you have at least 8075 reputation (as of Apr 23) and are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Math Stack Exchange t-shirt in your size
- Math Stack Exchange die-cut, vinyl stickers
- Math Stack Exchange mug
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/show/products/stack-exchange-sharpie)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: math.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: math.stackexchange.com sticker]

### The mug

[image: math.stackexchange.com mug]

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com) — direct links to [sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/show/products/stack-exchange-sharpie), [pens](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens), [stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store as soon as we're able)</sub>

Comment: Missed it by *that much!* (This is pretty cool though!)

Comment: Nice and thanks!

Comment: Pretty cool! Do the shirt come only in white, or are there black versions as well?

Comment: And, how many of those stickers would you send to the users?

Comment: @KannappanSampath: Judging by the ones I got from other SE sites, not very many, but more than I know what to do with :p.

Comment: My last bounty made me lost this chance :)

Comment: @Willie: So... one sticker? :-)

Comment: I was kinda hoping there'd be a choice of color on the shirt and mug, but I guess white is nice enough... :)

Comment: @JM: which color fits the red logo so good if not white?

Comment: Wow you guys rule! Apple pi and infinitely acute tan-gents!

Comment: Rebecca, will the swag arrive in a duffel bag with the caption "*Swag $$$*"?

Comment: I had a fake email address, and now have corrected it to a valid one. Hope I didn't miss the email!

Comment: @Aryabhata: Comedy kar rahe ho aap!

Comment: @Chandrasekhar: Free stuff! Yay!

Comment: I was told I would get some of this when I hit 100K; never got it, even though I e-mailed my shipping address...

Comment: @Aryabhata nope, you're good. (:

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff: Great! Thanks...

Comment: @Arturo I have your information and I am following up on this now. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Pretty cool! Many thanks!

Comment: Nice. Thank you!

Comment: Logistically infeasible, but really cool, would be the same t-shirt with the *signatures* of all the users on pages 1 and 2.

Comment: @MikeSpivey: I suppose we can arrange a math.SE conference and then everyone could sign my shirt... :-) [after all, it's white so I am the least likely person to wear and tear the signed shirt!]

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Sounds good!  I might attend that. :)

Comment: @MikeSpivey :) *points to username*-->

Comment: Nice idea. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Rebecca, In [Math SE Swag designs](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2491/math-se-swag-designs) a writing pad has been foreseen. I've searched for any writing pad in the [SE catalogue](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/show) and there's any. Just a curiosity, was it considered as not being interesting enough?

Comment: @MikeSpivey We could arrange that with the digitalization of the signature with some image processing software. Just sign in a blank page and vectorize it!

Comment: When will the T-shirt become available to mere mortals?

Comment: When will this actually happen? Still no sign of any loot arriving here.

Comment: @Mike It's not that difficult to get all the sought signatures since folks can easily upload images of the signatures (from scans or digital photos).

Comment: @BillDubuque: While quite feasible, how many of us do you think would willingly let such digital copies out into the wild, where they might find themselves affixed to various forms and contracts?

Comment: @Isaac Of course it would have to be organized by someone that the community trusts. I have seen analogous things done before. My point was merely to emphasize that it is feasible if done digitally.

Comment: @Asaf: would you instead take crytographically signed copies of my gravatar? (see Bill and Isaac's comments above)

Comment: @Willie: Only if you send it with that bottle of scotch! :-)

Comment: Hi, Rebecca, is there any chance to get these again?

Comment: @ShuhaoCao I no longer work for Stack Exchange.  You (or one of your moderators) would need to talk to any of the Community Team members. I'm not sure what their plans are.

Comment: [The Stack Exchange Shop has been closed since summer 2012.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137579/195817#137580 "What happened to the Stack Exchange Store?") Perhaps somebody should [edit] the question. (I would do it, but I don’t have the necessary privilege.)

Answer (score 16):

I received the package containing the following today, May $29^{th}$.

- One T-shirt
- One Mug
- One Stack Exchange Sticker
- One die-cut sticker
- One sharpie
- One pen

Thanks

Comment: I'm happy to see these finally arriving.

Comment: I also got that today (May 29).

Comment: Don't forget to mention the bubble wrap.

Comment: Same here. (And the box inside the box, too...)

Comment: Ok. I guess I have to wait a week or two more for overseas delivery. But thanks for telling about this! I now know I don't need to start worrying about it.

Comment: Nice! I hope to get mine soon!

Comment: Ok. The mail reached my Northern abode today. Thank you SE-team! Surprisingly fast shipping actually. I had to wait for my XKCD mail order for several months (and ask for it thrice - now I have two sets).

Comment: Yay mug. Yay bubble wrap. And yay small box which I can use to carry stuff in. (The large box, unfortunately was sacrificed: without a knife handy it was easier tearing up the box than peeling off tape.)

Comment: Just got mine. Thanks SE!

Comment: Received here as well. The postage is unbelievable!

Comment: No fair!  I got two sharpies and no pen!  Lament: white coffee mugs mean more washing for me... dark-colored mugs last longer before I notice the grunge building up inside...

Comment: Got mine too. Thanks a lot

Comment: I received the initial email saying I would receive a package but never the follow up email asking for an address. I thought the delay was for everyone but clearly not :(.

Comment: @RagibZaman I received only one email which also had a link to fill out the address. Below is the email.

Comment: Thank you for being one of the top http://math.stackexchange.com users!

As a small token of our appreciation, we'd like to send you a totally sweet, completely free Math Stack Exchange swag package, as documented here:

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4040/math-stack-exchange-top-user-swag

Just fill out the below form and we'll get it mailed out to you in 6 to 8 weeks -- no matter where in the world you live.

https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dDgzUUo5djVheHFrS2NROWJJUXN4SUE6MA#gid=0

p.s. you rock!

Comment: Ahh. I received that email, only read up to the link to this thread, and the OP in this thread wrote "You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences." so I thought another email was coming. Now I feel completely stupid for not finishing the original email lol. Thanks Marvis!

Comment: I liked the pen very much. If only it would come in black...

Comment: The Missus insisted on washing the shirt before I get to wear it at work. Before I made it that far she also pointed out the coffee stains on it. Dammit.

Comment: I got my shipment yesterday (June 8th).  I imagine Canada Customs was looking over it very carefully before releasing it to me.

Comment: I've just received all the items.

Comment: I was out of the country when the package arrived (May 30, I think). Thanks!

Comment: I got my box today: t-shirt, mug, pen, marker, stickers. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've just received the e-mail: How long will it take to receive the items? Or: How long did it take for you guys receive the items?