# How spirited is this community?

Tags: discussion

I apologize for the lack of tact and proper tone in my question description. I hope no one was terribly offended or struck by the utter ludicrousness of my question. I was just wondering if there was a store where users could buy clothes showcasing the community's logo or or specific ways this community has shown enthusiasm for itself.

Comment: [No](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store).

Comment: You realise April Fool's Day was *yesterday*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Exchange does produce "swag" items for this site. It is sent to elected moderators. It used to be sent to top users as well, but only [early in site's history](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4040).

Stack Exchange branded items are [not available for purchase](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137579).

A user selling merchandise  with Stack Exchange logo would be violating [trademark policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance):

> Do not use the names or logos owned by Stack Exchange Inc. on any apparel or merchandise without our permission.